# Boot Problems - Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: boot, mate

I have some serious boot problems. When I boot my ThinkPad T450s I can unlock my drive using normal Ubuntu password encryption. Then I get a kind of terminal (or shell, I guess its the same) and I can login myself. I figured out that I can boot when I type

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
sudo mount -a
sudo lightdm
```

I checked the boot.log in /var/log:

```
  lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
  Volume group "ubuntu-mate-vg" not found
  Cannot process volume group ubuntu-mate-vg
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Found volume group "ubuntu-mate-vg" using metadata type lvm2
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-mate-vg" now active
  /dev/mapper/ubuntu--mate--vg-root: clean, 657327/14786560 files, 34622765/59141120 blocks
```

So I guess there is something wrong in my fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=b14a41f2-a23b-494a-9524-f01ae898d61e /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=BFC3-1A74  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--mate--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

but I'm not that good on Ubuntu to figure out whtas wrong.

I also checked the the volume group by typing

```
sudo lvdisplay
```

Output:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-mate-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                ubuntu-mate-vg
  LV UUID                AsKTiD-ZGwk-7B9o-XWLt-rEMZ-usiM-TSK2uo
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-mate, 2016-05-10 08:13:22 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                225,61 GiB
  Current LE             57755
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-mate-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                ubuntu-mate-vg
  LV UUID                lJDLAc-sd6q-mJff-6Ds2-KrlK-sXSm-xxdoDw
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-mate, 2016-05-10 08:13:22 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                11,88 GiB
  Current LE             3041
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:2
```

Using pvs:

```
marius@marius-ThinkPad-T450s:~/Schreibtisch$ sudo pvs
  PV                     VG             Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt ubuntu-mate-vg lvm2 a--  237,49g 8,00m
```

I hope someone can help because I dont want to install everything new.
If you need further information please let me know!

Thanks in advance
marius

Comment: I don't know anything about FDE, but it seems odd to me that your fstab does not appear to have an entry for the root filesystem at all